# Disable out of stock options on a single product

Tags: php, woocommerce, code-snippets

I have an online store that sells retail fabric by length and I have been looking for a solution for distracted consumers when they try to buy an out-of-stock length (for instance, there are only 2 meters in stock and they select 3 meters); the fact is that they can select any unavailable option before seeing an out-of-stock message usually when they access their cart. I tried this snippet below but it produced no apparent effect; actually it was originally aimed at variable products. Is there a way to make it work on our specific store, greying out the unavailable lengths and disable them?

Thank You so much in advance for your time and support.
Best regards.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variation_is_active', 'bbloomer_grey_out_variations_out_of_stock', 10, 2 );

function bbloomer_grey_out_variations_out_of_stock( $is_active, $variation ) {

if ( ! $variation->is_in_stock() ) return false;

return $is_active;

}
```

Sample Product:
https://cristinamartinstecidos.com/loja/beubeu-azul-escuro/